# How to create (0,N)-shape compressed sparse matrix in SciPy?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am dependent upon an open-source library, Detectron, that initializes compressed sparse row (CSR) matrices in SciPy with shape (0,N), [like so](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/blob/master/lib/datasets/json_dataset.py#L150) (link to relevant line in GitHu repo):

```
 entry['gt_overlaps'] = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(
               np.empty((0, self.num_classes), 
               dtype=np.float32))
```

However the SciPy version I have available (0.12.1) does not support this (0,N) shape, and gives a ValueError:

> File
>   "/mnt/nfs/work1/elm/arunirc/Tools/detectron/lib/datasets/json_dataset.py",
>   line 150, in _prep_roidb_entry
>       np.empty((0, self.num_classes), dtype=np.float32)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line
>   66, in **init**
>       self._set_self( self.**class**(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)) )   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line
>   184, in **init**
>       self.shape = M.shape   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 74, in
>   set_shape
>       raise ValueError('invalid shape') ValueError: invalid shape

Is there any version of SciPy that does indeed support creating such CSR arrays? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just updating to the latest? It seems like the obvious first move.

Comment: @user2357112 there are some constraints (other packages installed on a shared cluster) and minimum version change is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok in the latest:

```
In [286]: scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(
     ...:                np.empty((0, 3), 
     ...:                dtype=np.float32))
     ...:                
Out[286]: 
<0x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [287]: scipy.__version__
Out[287]: '1.0.0'
```

It's not a very useful shape, but I can't think of a conceptual reason why it would be invalid.